# Need to Create temp table using ibatis

Tags: c#, ibatis

My project has some requirement to create temp table. I need to perform some operation on temp table like: -

1. Create table
2. Insert some data
3. Perform some operation on that data and update same.
4. Get that data from temp table.

I am able to perform all the operations while writing all queries in single statement, my sql mapper file look like this see below: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<sqlMap namespace="xxx" xmlns="http://ibatis.apache.org/mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <select id="GetTempTableData" resultClass="xxx" parameterClass="System.String">
     Create table ##TestTable(MatterID varchar(20), ShortDesc varchar(100))
     Insert into ##TestTable values('1001-101','ABC')
     Insert into ##TestTable values('1001-102','XYZ')
     Select * from ##TestTable
 </select>  
</sqlMap>
```

But i have a requirement to split all queries into seprate sections, see below: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<sqlMap namespace="xxx" xmlns="http://ibatis.apache.org/mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

 <select id="GetTempTableData" resultClass="xxx" parameterClass="System.String">
        Create table ##TestTable(MatterID varchar(20), ShortDesc varchar(100))
 </select>
 <insert id="InsertIntoTempTable" resultClass="xxx" parameterClass="System.String">
        Insert into ##TestTable values('1001-101','ABC')
        Insert into ##TestTable values('1001-102','XYZ')
 </insert>
 <select id="SelectFromTempTable" resultClass="xxx" parameterClass="System.String">
        Select * from ##TestTable
 </select>  
</sqlMap>
```

But in 2nd approach i am getting exception "Invalid object name #TestTable".
Can someone please suggest me, what should i do in that case?
Quick solution will highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did anyone figure out the root cause? iBatis version?